# Create a custom legend for multiple subplots

Tags: python, legend

I want to make scatter subplots, but I need to differentiate each marker according to column "Wall_construction". 
My data includes:
[content of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8b5h.png)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("forpythonultimo.csv")
grouped = df.groupby(["panel_coverage", "wwr"])
ncols= 5
nrows = int(np.ceil(grouped.ngroups/ncols))
cols = ['WWR {}'.format(col) for col in ['10%', '20%', '30%', '40%', '50%']]
rows = ['Panel {}'.format(row) for row in ['42%', '47%', '52%', '57%', '63%', '68%', '75%', '78%']]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(12, 4), sharex=True, sharey=True)
pad = 5

for (key, ax) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
    grouped.get_group(key).plot(x='disc_hours', y='Total_heat_gain', kind='scatter', subplots=True, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_title('')

for ax, col in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.annotate(col, xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
            xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
            size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

for ax, row in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.annotate(row, xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad - pad, 0),
            xycoords=ax.yaxis.label, textcoords='offset points',
            size='large', ha='right', va='center')
plt.show()
```

[Subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL9Ew.png)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried it in the code, but I think the usual legend is displayed as a list of `df['Wall_constraction']` and given to the label. The rest is up to you and your custom.

```
lbls = list(df['Wall_constraction'])
for (key, ax, l) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten(), lbls):
    grouped.get_group(key).plot(x='disc_hours', y='Total_heat_gain', kind='scatter', subplots=True, ax=ax, lable=l)
    ax.set_xlabel('')
    ax.set_ylabel('')
    ax.set_title('')
    ax.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1), borderaxespad=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did what you suggested but it is only printing 1 of the names in 'Wall_construction' in every subplot. Do you know how to solve this? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: There are two points that you have confirmed. First, is the element you want to display `lbls` with `print(ibls)`, second, is the element of `l` available with `for (key,ax,l) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten(),lbls): print(key, ax, l)`.